# Publish ASP.Net Application having Areas

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an application in asp.net MVC 4 which has multiple areas. On my local system, everything is working great but when I am deploying/Publishing it on the IIS server then the Areas project Views is not loading.

Project Directory
[image: a busy cat]

I have already tried these procedures which are available on the internet but didn't get success.
I added these codes in my main project .csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
          CustomDeployAreas;
          $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
          CustomDeployAreas;
          $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Procedure 2 -->
<Target Name="CustomDeployAreas">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AreasFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Areas\**" />
        <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(AreasFiles.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>Areas\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
      <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
          CustomDeployAreas;
          $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
          CustomDeployAreas;
          $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
      </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

when I am accessing the areas URL then it shows "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

Here is the image URL of error https://ibb.co/v1JsKhP

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: In your area, you have added layout page?

Comment: yes, I have added the layout page and controller also

Comment: Please publish project in Release mode and check area folder include or not

Comment: Yes, at the time of publishing release mode is selected and area project is published under the Areas folder.

Comment: You have created areas project inside MVC application or separate project?

Comment: Separate project

Comment: separate project not work in one application directory you need to publish individual and put on **IIS Server** same pool in creating parent and child folder.

Comment: I have published both project individually and uploaded them on the server under the same pool and served area project as a child project in main project. The problem which I am facing only is view loading

Comment: Yes, the reason behind both the project has own solution file and own references you need to map then published MVC application to Area application.

Comment: I have already added the reference of the child project in the main project.

Comment: Ok, we need to hard testing, your application working locally?

Comment: Yes, on the local system everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Please debug maybe local code include your MVC areas.

Comment: I didn't understand your point. can you explain about it in details?